# Filter Placeholders with Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

Does anyone know how to implement a placeholder or tooltip on the Gridview filter of the Yii2 Framework? I need something that stands out to the user to let them know that textbox is in fact a search filter.

Look forward to hearing responses.

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Placeholder could be realized with this:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel'  => $searchModel,
    'columns'      => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'filterInputOptions' => [
                'class'       => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'Type in some characters...'
             ]
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn' ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

`class` should be provided, though it is not a must - it is just the default styling class.

**Setting this globally**

The only way that I found is in *config/web.php* that is used for the application configuration:

```
$config = [
    ...
    'on beforeRequest'          => function ($event) {
        Yii::$container->set('yii\grid\DataColumn', [
            'filterInputOptions' => [
                'class'       => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'Type in some characters...'
            ]
        ]);
    },
    ...
];
```

This is an [event handler](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#eventbeforerequest). On each request DataColumn will be configured to use the placeholder. Some detail information can be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html#practical-usage). Now you don't need to adjust any GridView configuration in order to have the placeholder. In the handler you can change other configurations as well, of course.

Comment: Thanks very much this works like a charm. One more thing, if I wanted to apply this all my Gridviews application wide, how would I go about doing this, rather than manually going to each Gridview and applying it to each column?

Comment: @user2818986 Updated my post. But I don't know if this the only or best approach.

Comment: Right brilliant thanks very much. Will use your solution. I suppose most functions application wide should be placed in the config file, completely forgot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

yon can also use the `tooltip/title` with `filterOptions`

```
 [
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'label' => 'labelname',
            ...
            ....
            'filterOptions' => [ 'title' => 'prova'],
        ],
```